# How to modify, in list over which I iterate with enumerate, another line than that on which the iteration has arrived?

Tags: python, list, replace, line, enumerate

In the following iteration, once the conditions to find a line are satisfied, how can I modify and write to the text file containing the list,a line situated at "n" lines distance from the one where the iteration has arrived?

```
    llll=['aaa','ww','emmm','wiguy','ynof','sijegy']
    mfw=open(r"D:\file.txt",'r')
    listmfw=mfw.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(listmfw):
            if line != '\n':
                if not (line.split()[0] in llll):
                    if (line.strip('\n') == 'wiguy'):
                    i=i-42
                    print('zugyt')

#As the line where I want to write is empty,I tried:
                    line=line.replace('\n\',''zugyt')
```

But nothing happens

I added what was missing - typing error!

Comment: What you mean by 'nothing happens'? This code shouldn't even parse due to ```if not (line.split()[0] in ):```.

Comment: Could you provide an example input and output?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may misunderstand what python's file interface does. Even if you changed the open to read/write and then wrote to the file, all that would do is overwrite what's in the file at the point you write. You may want to look at `fileinput`, below replaces all blank newlines with 'Test\n':

```
from __future__ import print_function
import fileinput

file = fileinput.input('test.txt', inplace=1)
for line in file:
    if line == '\n':
        print('Test')
    else:
        print(line, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution which writes what I need in the position I need,relative to another position which is found by the specified conditionis.This is: :

```
    mfw=open(r"D:\file.txt",'r')
    listmfw=mfw.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(listmfw):
            if line != '\n':
                #if not (line.split()[0] in llll):
                    if (line.strip('\n') == 'wiguy'):
                        listmfw[i-43]='bzz'
                        out = open(r"D:\Users\cristina\Documents\horia\Linguistics\file.txt", 'w')
                        out.writelines(listmfw)
                        listmfw[i-31]='vrrr'
                        out.writelines(listmfw)
                        listmfw[i-19]='dopiu'
                        out.writelines(listmfw)
                    if (line.strip('\n') == 'emmm'):
                        listmfw[i-13]='ommm'
                        out.writelines(listmfw)
                    if (line.strip('\n') == 'sijegy'):
                        listmfw[i-19]='mrrr'
                        out.writelines(listmfw)
                        out.flush()
                        out.close()
    mfw.close()
```

Comment: Congrats, just a couple of comments. I would be cautious of putting the output file management in the if statements, it relies on a specific path being followed, e.g. if `emmm\n` comes before `wiguy\n` this would result in an error as out will not be initialised. Also you don't really need the `mfw.readlines` call as this reads the whole file into memory just using `for i, line in enumerate(mfw):` would work fine and just deal with one line at a time in memory. I would also look at the `with` statement for your first line.